# Is it possible to set accent colors for pptx4j in groovy?

Tags: groovy, docx4j

I'd like to set the accent colors belonging to `ST_SchemeColorVal` in Groovy.
Something like:

```
 STSchemeColorVal.ACCENT_1 = new Color(0,0,0)
```

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to change the a:accent1 element in your theme part (or one of your theme parts), for example:

```
    <a:theme name="Office Theme">
        <a:themeElements>
            <a:clrScheme name="Custom 1">
                <a:dk1>
                    <a:srgbClr val="2F2B20"/>
                </a:dk1>
                <a:lt1>
                    <a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/>
                </a:lt1>
                <a:dk2>
                    <a:srgbClr val="675E47"/>
                </a:dk2>
                <a:lt2>
                    <a:srgbClr val="DFDCB7"/>
                </a:lt2>
                <a:accent1>
                    <a:srgbClr val="D6F23C"/>
                </a:accent1>
                <a:accent2>
                    <a:srgbClr val="9CBEBD"/>
                </a:accent2>
                :
                <a:accent6>
                    <a:srgbClr val="B1A089"/>
                </a:accent6>
                <a:hlink>
                    <a:srgbClr val="D25814"/>
                </a:hlink>
                <a:folHlink>
                    <a:srgbClr val="849A0A"/>
                </a:folHlink>
            </a:clrScheme>
```

You need to get the theme part, then change the value of the relevant element.

Creating the content from scratch is a different question, but in Java would be something like:

```
    org.docx4j.dml.ObjectFactory dmlObjectFactory = new org.docx4j.dml.ObjectFactory();

    CTColorScheme colorscheme = dmlObjectFactory.createCTColorScheme(); 
    this.getContents().getThemeElements().setClrScheme(colorscheme);
        // Create object for accent1
        CTColor color = dmlObjectFactory.createCTColor(); 
        colorscheme.setAccent1(color); 
            // Create object for srgbClr
            CTSRgbColor srgbcolor = dmlObjectFactory.createCTSRgbColor(); 
            color.setSrgbClr(srgbcolor);

            srgbcolor.setVal(your byte[])
```